# python program that translates a secret message into real alphabet

Tags: python, linux, dictionary

i have made this dictionary as a secret language and when the user enters a sentence in the secret language it should return in real alphabet, this is the code i wrote .

```
secret = {'b' : 'a', 'c' : 'b', 'd' : 'c', 'e' : 'd', 'f' : 'e', 'g' : 'f', 'h' : 'g', 'i' : 'h', 'j' : 'i', 'k' : 'j', 'l' : 'k', 'm' : 'l', 'n' : 'm', 'o' : 'n', 'p' : 'o', 'q' : 'p', 'r' : 'q', 's' : 'r', 't' : 's', 'u' : 't', 'v' : 'u', 'w' : 'v', 'x' : 'w', 'y' : 'x', 'z' : 'y', 'a' : 'z'}

user = raw_input('Please Input A Secret Sentence :')

print (secret[user])
```

so i got it to work but it only works when entering 1 letter it doesn't work with a sentence it gives this error :

```
[student@localhost 1]$ python idk24.py
Please Input A Secret Sentence :aaa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "idk24.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (secret[user])
KeyError: 'aaa'
```

Comment: In order to "complete the rest of the code", you have to write *some* code.

Comment: i improved it .

Comment: @ScottHunter i have can you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script you have multiple numbers `aaa` that you pass as a dictionary.  There is not such value in the dictionary, hence your error.

This is what I would suggest:

Try defining a new variable and split up the user input into single letters with a for loop.  Add each individual letter to the entire encoded sentence and print it at the end:

```
secret = {'b' : 'a', 'c' : 'b', 'd' : 'c', 'e' : 'd', 'f' : 'e', 'g' : 'f', 'h' : 'g', 'i' : 'h', 'j' : 'i', 'k' : 'j', 'l' : 'k', 'm' : 'l', 'n' : 'm', 'o' : 'n', 'p' : 'o', 'q' : 'p', 'r' : 'q', 's' : 'r', 't' : 's', 'u' : 't', 'v' : 'u', 'w' : 'v', 'x' : 'w', 'y' : 'x', 'z' : 'y', 'a' : 'z'}

user = raw_input('Please Input A Secret Sentence :')
entire = ""
for i in user:
    entire = entire + secret[i]    

print (entire)
```